# Problems extending JPanels

Tags: java, swing

Hi I'm working on a problem and I'm having some issues working in Swing. I have no issues working with classes that extend either JFrame or JComponent, but when I try to use a class that I write that extends JPanel, it won't ever show up and nothing that I call on that panel shows up, including adding custom JComponents to it. What is the general procedure for creating a JPanel extendting class and then setting it as the content pane to use in a JFrame?

Comment: "Extends" implies an is-a relationship. Unless you're making a lightweight container, don't extend `JPanel`.

Comment: For more focused help, please provide a representative [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I (my personal view) can't see nothing wrong with extends `JComponent` as `JComponent`, `JPanel`, `JLabel`, more [Inheritance versus composition](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html), for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CustomComponent extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomComponent() {
        setTitle("Custom Component Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new CustomComponents());
        pack();
        setMinimumSize(getSize());// enforces the minimum size of both frame and component
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CustomComponent main = new CustomComponent();
                //main.display();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomComponents extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 300);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int margin = 10;
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(margin, margin, dim.width - margin * 2, dim.height - margin * 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be added your class that extend the Jpanel to a container like JFrame.A class that extends the JPanel it not show any things because it a component not container.