# Graphics2D using constructor

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I want to draw a straight line in JFrame using `Line2D.Double`, also I want do it with constructor (not through method). How I must declare variable g like in example on [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html)?

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Painting is always done in a method. In particular custom painting in Swing is done in the paintComponent() method of a Swing component like JComponent or JPanel.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for a better explanation and examples.

Answer (score 2):

1) `I want to draw a straight line in JFrame using Line2D.Double`, that not possible you have to put there [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) or plain JComponent, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114842/problems-extending-jpanels/8115246#8115246)

2) if you want to `paint` directly to the `JFrame`, then you have to (use method `paint()`) to the `GlassPane` or `RootPane`

3) for Swing is there method `painComponent`(as mentioned both posters), not `paint`

Answer (score 1):

The drawing/painting occurs event driven. That is when a part of the JFrame has to be (re-)drawn paint and paintComponent will be called.

You can merely add a component to the content pane of the JFrame in the constructor. That would then draw the line by overriding paintComponent.

You could create a JPanel, which has a:

```
List<Shape> shapes;
shapes.add(new Line2D.Double(...));
```

and then in paintComponent draw all shapes. But that is overdone.

Answer (score -2):

You mean how to get a `Graphics2D` object from with a constructor? That is not the way to do it, `Graphics2D` is an interface and the implementation classes are not in the API. However, you can get a graphics object from any component with

```
(Graphics2D)component.getGraphics()
```

Comment: -1 Don't use getGraphics(). The painting is only temporary and will be lost the next time Swing determines the components needs to be repainted.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the downvote! Maybe this is a solution for temporary painting?